# Is there a way to get a list of hidden column

Tags: bootstrap-table

I want to save the list of hidden columns so that next time when the table is loaded I show the table with the same set of column which the user chose to see in the past. Is there a way to get a list of all hidden columns in bootstrap-table library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cookie extension to solve your problem, here is an example: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/cookie.html.

The plugin saves:

- Sort order
- Page number
- Page number from the list
- Visible columns
- Search text

Docs here: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-cookie

Answer (score 0):

you can use the jquery datatables plugin to easily handle this problem, this plugin auto generate the table columns and show that.

you will get more information from link below,
https://www.datatables.net/

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this below

```
var tab = $('#table').bootstrapTable('getHiddenColumns');
$.each(tab, function(index, value) {
    alert(value.title);
})
```